# Linear Mixed Model using R - what is the syntax when there are within-subject variables of both fixed and random nature?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, interaction

I am new to R and to mixed linear modelling. I have a dataset with variables from a cross-sectional study looking at fractional anisotrophy (a property of the brains white matter) in 6 different white matter fibre tracts in the brain. For each fibre tract there are 2 measures (one from each hemispheres). There are 66 participants divided into two groups. We want to control the group comparisons for differences in age, the average FA volume across the brain (wholebrain FA) and tract volume.

I assume that Group (Patients/Controls), Tract (CB/SLF1/SLF2/SLF3/UF/OFST) and Hemisphere (Left/Right) are fixed effects and that Subject (n=66) is a random effect. I also assume that Age, Wholebrain FA and Tract volume should be modelled as fixed effects. For Age and Wholebrain FA there is one value for each participants, but for Volume there is one value for each observation. The attached picture presents the table in the long format. For each subject there is 12 observations.

[image]

We hypothesized that there would be group difference in each of the six fibre tracts. We had no a priori assumptions about the hemispheres but would like to explore this post-hoc. We would also like to explore associations between Age and FA in different tracts.

My suggested model look like this

```
mixed.lmer <- lmer(FA ~ Age + Wholebrain_FA + Volume + Group * Tract * Hemisphere + 
                     (1|Subjects), data = DTI)
```

**Question 1**: Given that Tract and Hemisphere are assumed to be fixed variables but also are within-subject variables, are they correctly modelled? I am having a hard time understanding how the model "understand" that these variables have multiple levels from the way its written above.

**Question 2**: The Volume variable is a within-subject variable whereas Age is a between subject variable. Should they then not be modelled differently?

**Question 3**: Whether or not to include a three-way interaction is a major debate in my research group. Some saying that for practical purposes its impossible to really make sense of it. Other say it can guide the decision of whether or not to test differences between groups for each hemisphere in each tract. Including a three way interaction to the model is likely to change the results significantly so it seems pretty important to get it right the first time. Any thought on this? Is it being a criminal to include it?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the between-subject and within-subject distinction becomes more confusing than it is useful. Think about what your model implies as it is written, putting aside the random effect for now:

> In your model, each fractional anisotropy (FA) measurement of a region represents a sum of contributions from a set of predictors. Added to an overall (implied) intercept value is a contribution proportional to the age of the individual, one proportional to whole-brain FA, one proportional to the region's volume, and a set of contributions each proportional to some combination of group and tract and hemisphere.

Is that what you intend? If so, it's OK.

Even if you think of age and whole-brain FA as "between-subject" variables, your model simply says that the regional FA values of all 6 regions in both hemispheres are affected to the same additive amount by the age and whole-brain FA of the individual in whom the measurements are made. If that's consistent with your knowledge of the subject matter then what you have written for them is OK.

The random effect as you have written it allows for differences among individuals in the intercept values to which the contributions from the fixed effects will be added. In your model, the proportionality coefficients for contributions from age, whole-brain FA, and for the combinations of group, tract, and hemisphere will not differ among the individuals. Again, that's OK if it's consistent with your knowledge of the subject matter.

You are adding a lot of predictors to the model by including all those interactions. That reduces the number of degrees of freedom left for statistical tests, thus running a risk of losing power to detect true associations between your predictors and the regional FA measurements. That risk has to be balanced off against the possibility that the interactions (potentially, even the admittedly hard-to-interpret 3-way interactions) do matter. That decision again depends on your knowledge of the subject matter. Consider pulling back on some of the interaction terms. It's not clear to me why, for example, you expect systematic additive effects of left versus right hemisphere and of *all the interactions involving hemisphere* that are the same from individual to individual. PubMed lists [over 9000 papers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=fractional+anisotropy) involving FA measurement, so that extensive literature should help inform your decision about the interactions that are worth incorporating.